# Multi-layer sorting in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

Im having trouble figuring out how to write a multi-layer sort using a scope method in my model, which can sort through the model's attributes, as well as its related child models' attributes?

To put more concretely, I have the following models, each a related child of the previous one (I excluded other model methods and declarations for brevity):

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :questions
  # would like to write multi-layer sort here 
end 

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :course, :counter_cache => true
  has_many: :answers

end 

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :question, :counter_cache => true
end
```

I would like to sort courses first by `questions_count` (through my `counter_cache`), **then** by `answer_count`, and lastly by `created_at`, and was wondering how I could string everything together into a single scope method to put in my `Course` model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen here (creating a scope with a joined model) : [problem: activerecord (rails3), chaining scopes with includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393013/problem-activerecord-rails3-chaining-scopes-with-includes)

And here (sorting with multiple columns) : [Ruby on Rails: how do I sort with two columns using ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587776/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-sort-with-two-columns-using-activerecord)

And finally here (sorting by associated model) : [Rails 3. sort by associated model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336089/rails-3-sort-by-associated-model)

You may achieve this like so :

```
scope :complex_sorting, lambda {
    joins(:questions)
    .order('questions_count DESC, question.answers_count DESC, created_at DESC')
}
```

Comment: Typing in the code as seen above resulted in a "tried to create Proc object without a block" error.  After seeing a similar issue raised, I reformatted the code as `scope :by_most_popular, lambda { |course| 
    joins(:question).order('questions_count DESC, question.answers_count DESC, created_at DESC')
  }`.  However, now Ruby is complaining that "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"

Comment: Updated my answer to replace "do...end" with curly brackets. Do you have more precisions regarding the "wrong number of arguments error (0 for 1)" ?

Comment: I did a bit more digging around to find out whats behind the "wrong arguments" error.  I rewrote a simpler scope method to test if the joins is working (`scope :by_answer_count, -> {
    joins(:question).order('question.answers_count DESC')
  }`) and I got the error "Association named 'question' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?".  Given the way the models are related, i don't see why its can't find the `question` model.  I think its likely this was throwing the more complex sorting method off.

Comment: Just discovered that whenever I add in `|course|` to the method (the simple or complex one), I get the argument error.

Comment: Maybe it's `:questions` and not `:question` given the `has_many` relation ?

Comment: Thanks, this indeed happened to be the cause.  However, anytime I put up the vertical bars in `|course|` I would always get the argument error.  Im running ruby 1.9.3 p194.. and can't seem to figure out why it can't take the lambda.

Comment: My mistake, I think you don't need to pass the argument (as your first error said) juste remove the `|course|`. It is used in case you pass an argument to your scope... sorry about that

Comment: Thank you, especially for following up my questions!   We are very close I think (it now renders the view instead of throwing the error). However, the part `questions.answers_count DESC` is displaying `courses` at the number of `questions` each course has.. in other words, showing repetitions of the same course.  The logic seems solid, and I can't figure out why it wouldn't do as it should..

Comment: Ah sorry.. so currently, I only have one `Course` populated.  So when I run in console `Course.all.count`, I get `=> 1`.  However, when running `Course.complex_sorting.count`, I get `=>3`.  The reason for this 3 is due to the fact that my Course currently has 3 questions populated.. but it seems to have taken this sum and displayed the same Course three times.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23872/discussion-between-sparda-and-daspianist)